# Is there any funds that do market making?

Tags: market-making, funds

In spite of banks, market making firms, brokers is there any funds that specially do market making?

Answer (score 2):

Of course, Citadel as a primary example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, although they might not remain funds for very long. Market making is not a particularly capital intensive activity, and it can be quite profitable (or at least, rather risk-adjusted returns are high) so once the fund owners have accumulated some profit they will be incentivised to return outside capital and operate as a stand-alone business.

Comment: Can you explain more and give some examples, please